# .NET Only Column name in Exception.ErrorMessage

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, exception, sqldatareader

I have logged the exceptions that occur in my windows service into Database. To log the exception, I've used Exception.ErrorMessage.
Following is code:

```
        mailAddress = ""
        queryString = "SELECT Column1 FROM TableName WHERE Column2= 'Value' "

        dataReader = _dataAccess.ExecuteReader(queryString)

        If dataReader.Read Then
            If Not IsDBNull(dataReader.Item("Column1")) Then
                mailAddress = CType(dataReader.Item("Column1"), String)
            End If
        End If
```

The Catch block is:

```
Catch ex As Exception
        LogIntoDataBase(ex.Message)
End Try
```

The error occurs rarely and Database only contains "ColumnName", nothing else.

I have figured out that if select query does not contain the Column1 and DataReader tries to read it, then an Exception is thrown where ErrorMessage only contains Column Name. but here, everything is static, query is never changed and will always select the "Column1".

I have done with guess game. What else can be logged here so that an exception which occurs once in a month can be caught with cause. OR can someone guess what can be the problem in code?

Comment: If you catch database errors and log them **to the database**, what happens when the database is unavailable? (connectionstring issue, server is down, user rights issue, ...) How would you expect to see any logging? Secondly, if you are getting an exception, can you please put that in your question so we at least know what's going wrong?

Comment: Minor update because I think I get what you mean: If you are getting an exception with only the column name in the message; then there is a custom exception being thrown somewhere. Every automatically generated exception that I've come across has a more verbose message. Look for custom exceptions that are being thrown by your application (or any library you reference).

Comment: Thanks for the scenarios. For time being we have logged the exception into database, as the project architecture currently allow this in simple way. About the exception, I have mentioned that I only get "Column1" in the exception. that is, only  name of exception. Please note this is logged exception and not caught at time of debugging. It was not occurred when we tried to reproduce by debugging.

Comment: I think my second comment already addresses this. Also, if you want to have a full exception (not just its message), do it like this: `LogIntoDataBase(ex.ToString())` This will print out the entire exception including a stack trace. You can use the stack trace to find where the exception was thrown from. That only takes you to the _source_ of the exception, but it's a good start on the way to figuring out what is going wrong.

Comment: @Flater yes, we have custom exceptions being thrown. The Exception is converted into Custom Exception and I am using ErrorMessage of customException. I must say you are genius for your guess. please suggest what can be done.

Comment: I think my previous comment (again ;)) addresses what approach you should take. If you make your logging more verbose, you will be able to pinpoint the cause of the issue. Without a proper description of the problem (in the exception), no one can really help you.

Comment: Thanks @Flater.. and it was page refresh issue, I read those comments after I posted mine :)

Comment: I have voted to close this question as we cannot help without a proper error description. When you find the source of the exception and can't fix it, you can open a new question to help you with the actual underlying problem.